# Can't connect sql with visual studio 2010

Tags: database

I have a project that attached database in visual studio .

when i add information to program and click on record.. the comment is : record success but in sql don't add anything ... this is my code

```
  string connection_string = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"" + Application.StartupPath + "\\entekhab_vahed.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

my sql version is Management studio R2 ... in server explorer connection is unStable ...

first i changed connection through modyfi conection/advand and changed data source to "." and in conection code i changed Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS to Data Source=. and when i close Sql , conection goes to stable(test connection sucsess) and i changed code to this : (in app.config and program)

```
 string connection_string = "Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=\"" + Application.StartupPath + "\\entekhab_vahed.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

i get this error:

```
The database 'C:\MADRASE\MADRASE\ENTEKHAB_VAHED\BIN\X86\DEBUG\ENTEKHAB_VAHED.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
```

and get this error too :

```
Error   11  Could not copy "C:\madrase\madrase\entekhab_vahed\entekhab_vahed.mdf" to "bin\x86\Debug\entekhab_vahed.mdf". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.    entekhab_vahed
```

second i detach the database and add it to data connection through local ..

and this is my connection code :

```
"Data Source =.;Initial Catalog = ENTEKHAB_VAHED;Integrated Security = True
```

i get this error :
`
Cannot open database "ENTEKHAB_VAHED" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'Babak-PC\Babak'`.

This is very important to me , i Want add sql with my visual studio and i have problem in many way .

any professional member can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that 'Babak-PC\Babak' doesn't have access to the database. In SQL server management studio, look at security -> users in your database and see if the user is there.

However, I would strongly recommend creating a new SQL user that your application will use to connect to the database, rather than using Windows authentication. To do this, you will need to enable [Mixed Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx). Then you will need to [create a login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) for sql server and [create a user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx) for the database that is associated with that login. Then you can give specific permissions to that user in the database (e.g. create, insert, update, execute, etc.)

Then your connection string will look like:

```
"Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=\"" + Application.StartupPath + "\\entekhab_vahed.mdf\";User Id=newUserName;Password=newPassword;Connect Timeout=30"
```